# Sequelize upsert() never updates and only inserts

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, upsert

So I'm trying to use the `model.upsert()` of `sequelize` and all i receive is inserts , no matter what i change in the query.

I have a Transaction model that has some fields, with the default generated id.

reading the sequelize's `upsert` documentation i noticed this:

> An update will be executed if a row which matches the supplied values on either the primary key or a unique key is found. Note that the unique index must be defined in your sequelize model and not just in the table.

So i was guessing i have to define the `id` of the Transaction in the model definition, and so i did with no luck as it still only creates new entries..

```
TransactionModel = {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    {.......}
}
```

What am i doing wrong, what did i miss?

Any explanation and solution will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

This is the upsert code:

```
createOrUpdateTransaction: {
            type: Transaction,
            args: {
                payerAccountNumber: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)},
                recipientAccountNumber: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)},
                amount: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat)},
                currency: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                paymentMethod: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                cardNumber: {type: GraphQLFloat},
                cardName: {type: GraphQLString},
                cardNetwork: {type: GraphQLString},
                cashMachineId: {type: GraphQLFloat},
                receiptNumber: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat)},
                invoiceNumber: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat)},
                receiptCopy: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                description: {type: GraphQLString},
                bankDescription: {type: GraphQLString},
                bankReference: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                bankSubCurrencyAccount: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                tags: {type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)},
                notes: {type: GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => {
                return db.models.transaction.upsert({
                    time: new Date().toString(),
                    payerAccountNumber: args.payerAccountNumber,
                    recipientAccountNumber: args.recipientAccountNumber,
                    amount: args.amount,
                    currency: args.currency,
                    paymentMethod: args.paymentMethod,
                    cardNumber: args.cardNumber,
                    cardName: args.cardName,
                    cardNetwork: args.cardNetwork,
                    cashMachineId: args.cashMachineId,
                    receiptNumber: args.receiptNumber,
                    invoiceNumber: args.invoiceNumber,
                    receiptCopy: args.receiptCopy,
                    description: args.description,
                    bankDescription: args.bankDescription,
                    bankReference: args.bankReference,
                    bankSubCurrencyAccount: args.bankSubCurrencyAccount,
                    tags: args.tags,
                    notes: args.notes,
                    bankAccountAccountNumber: args.payerAccountNumber
                })
            }
        }
```

As this is part of a `Mutation` in `GraphQL`.

It might be worth noting that this was `addTransaction` before and all i changed was to `db.models.transaction.upsert()` from `db.models.transaction.create()`

Comment: Having never used sequelize, my complete guess here is that the autoIncrement aspect (or something you're doing with it) is messing you up somehow.

Comment: Manually creating transaction in the DB does produce sequential id so i guess that one is fine. with or without this id (meaning with the default generated id) it only inserts

Comment: Are you sure the ID you are using when upserting is a Number? Wouldn't surprise me if it fails if it's a string.

Comment: @GrimurD When I'm using the default generated ID it supposed to always be a number, and when i set my `id` on the Transaction model, you can see i defined it as `Sequelize.INTEGER`, and used `autoIncreament` so its supposed to be automatically

Comment: I mean when you are upserting you must specify the ID of the model that may or may not exist(if id is undefined/null it is inserted not updated, but if the id is a Number and it is found in the db, it's updated). And I wanted to make sure that the ID when you are upserting is a valid number.

Comment: @GrimurD I read the documentation http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#upsertvalues-options-promisecreated and it looks like you use `upsert` just like you'd use `create`, passing it data for the entry and it checks if it exists or not by the id of the model, do i misunderstand it?

Comment: Well you must make sure you are actually passing in the ID of the model if it already exists so it is found. But what I meant that when you do, you must make sure it is of the correct type. Even if the id is 1 you must make sure it's a number but not for example a string. If it's a string it might not match.

Comment: @GrimurD to make it clear, this is how i upsert => `db.models.transaction.upsert(transaction);`, if i understand you correctly, you're saying this is not the right way and im missing validating the id even if the id is generated. please do explain how to use `upsert` with an example, highly appreciate it

Comment: Please update your question with a more detailed code sample showing how you are doing upsert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your upsert() example you aren't providing the *id* of the entry into the upsert method. This means sequelize can't match the *id* to a row (because the *id* is undefined) and therefore it inserts a new row.

Even if you use a different primary key it must always be a property for it to match since sequelize uses the primary key to search for an existing row.

```
createOrUpdateTransaction: {
    type: Transaction,
    args: {
        // Omitted code...
    },
    resolve: (root, args) => {
        return db.models.transaction.upsert({
            // The id property must be defined in the args object for 
            // it to match to an existing row. If args.id is undefined 
            // it will insert a new row.
            id: args.id, 
            time: new Date().toString(),
            payerAccountNumber: args.payerAccountNumber,
            recipientAccountNumber: args.recipientAccountNumber,
            amount: args.amount,
            currency: args.currency,
            paymentMethod: args.paymentMethod,
            cardNumber: args.cardNumber,
            cardName: args.cardName,
            cardNetwork: args.cardNetwork,
            // Omitted fields ...
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey again GrimurD, thanks for all the help. Yet I'm unable to understand what am i supposed to do if the id of my row is just the default sequential generated id?

Comment: When you retrieve a transaction one of the properties of the transaction is the id. I assume that at some point you are retrieving the transaction before you update it? Well you use the id you got when you retrieved it to update it. If you can't do that, upsert is not the method to use. Instead you will have to use some of the properties you have in the args object to find if there is already a row with those values. Then if it finds something you update that. If it doesn't you will do a regular create(). I don't think I can explain it any better :)

Comment: Well thanks a lot, that worked, ill give an edit to your answer about the generated ids :)