# Sequelize Upsert is Creating instead of Updating

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

According to the documentation found [here](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/model/#upsertvalues-options-promisecreated) it states as follows

`upsert(values, [options]) -> Promise.<created>`

> Insert or update a single row. An update will be executed if a row which matches the supplied values on either the primary key or a unique key is found. Note that the unique index must be defined in your sequelize model and not just in the table. Otherwise you may experience a unique constraint violation, because sequelize fails to identify the row that should be updated.

So my expectation is that upserting using a unique key should replace the existing value. However when my code runs instead of updating the existing database record, it adds a new one. What am I doing wrong?

here is a sample of my model

```js
'use strict'

module.exports = (db, dataTypes) => {
  const titanJob = db.define('titanJob', {
    titanId: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    name: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  })
  return titanJob
}
```

and here is an example of my upsert

```js
await asyncForEach(res.data.hits.hits, async es => {
  const src = es._source
  try {
    await titanJob.upsert({
      name: src.name,
      titanId: src.id,
    }, { titanId: src.id })
    logger.debug(`[${file}] upsert successful`)
  } catch (err) {
    logger.warn(`[${file}] failed to save to database`)
    logger.warn(`[${file}] ${err}`)
  }
})
```

Comment: Please refer to the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413188/4068817. I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

First you should add a unique index (constraint) to your table. The data you upserting should contain the field set of the unique index (constraint).

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing a unique constraint on `titanId`, chances are you want to make it a primary key, like below. Primary key already has a unique constraint so you don't need to add another one. Primary key also makes it much easier for search, as all you need is `findByPk(titanId)`. Without setting primary key, Sequelize would have to create two indexes - one for `id` and the other one for `titanId` where a unique key is given - which is not a way to save space.

Also, primary key is what `upsert()` replies upon at search - without it `upsert()` simply inserts another record - which is the cause behind your problem and many similar ones on StackOverflow.

```js
titanId: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      // primary key needs no unique constraint
      // primary key cannot be nullable
}
```

Another way around making `titanId` your primary key is to place a unique constraint on both `id` and `titanId` - assuming you believe there could be multiple records for one `titanId`. This would create an index on `id` and `titanId`, and `upsert()` using these two fields is guaranteed to find the right record and update it.

```js
module.exports = (db, dataTypes) => {
  const titanJob = db.define('titanJob', {
    id: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: 'unique_id_titanId', // or whatever name you like
    },
    titanId: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: 'unique_id_titanId', // must be exactly the same as above
    },
    name: {
      type: dataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  })
  return titanJob
}
```

```js
await titanJob.upsert({id, titanId, name});
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work. Here is an example using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import assert from 'assert';

class TitanJob extends Model {}
TitanJob.init(
  {
    titanId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'titanJob', timestamps: true },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const datas = [
      { titanId: '1', name: 'programmer' },
      { titanId: '2', name: 'teacher' },
    ];
    const jobs = await TitanJob.bulkCreate(datas);
    assert.deepEqual(
      jobs.map((job) => ({ titanId: job.id, name: job.name })),
      datas,
      'Should bulk create programmer and teacher datas',
    );
    const rval = await TitanJob.upsert({ titanId: '1', name: 'driver' }, { returning: true });
    assert.equal(rval[0].titanId, '1', 'Should update the row which titanId is "1"');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

Execution results:

```sh
{ POSTGRES_HOST: '127.0.0.1',
  POSTGRES_PORT: '5430',
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'testpass',
  POSTGRES_USER: 'testuser',
  POSTGRES_DB: 'node-sequelize-examples' }
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "titanJob" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "titanJob" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "titanJob" ("id"   SERIAL , "titanId" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'titanJob' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "titanJob" ("id","titanId","name","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'1','programmer','2020-02-14 08:09:45.506 +00:00','2020-02-14 08:09:45.506 +00:00'),(DEFAULT,'2','teacher','2020-02-14 08:09:45.506 +00:00','2020-02-14 08:09:45.506 +00:00') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.sequelize_upsert(OUT created boolean, OUT primary_key text)  AS $func$ BEGIN INSERT INTO "titanJob" ("titanId","name","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('1','driver','2020-02-14 08:09:45.524 +00:00','2020-02-14 08:09:45.524 +00:00') RETURNING "id" INTO primary_key; created := true; EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN UPDATE "titanJob" SET "titanId"='1',"name"='driver',"updatedAt"='2020-02-14 08:09:45.524 +00:00' WHERE ("id" IS NULL OR "titanId" = '1') RETURNING "id" INTO primary_key; created := false; END; $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; SELECT * FROM pg_temp.sequelize_upsert();
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "titanId", "name", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "titanJob" AS "titanJob" WHERE "titanJob"."id" = '1';
```

No assertion fails. It works as expected. Check the data rows in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "titanJob";
 id | titanId |  name   |         createdAt          |         updatedAt
----+---------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  2 | 2       | teacher | 2020-02-14 08:09:45.506+00 | 2020-02-14 08:09:45.506+00
  1 | 1       | driver  | 2020-02-14 08:09:45.506+00 | 2020-02-14 08:09:45.524+00
(2 rows)
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/59686743